# NameError: name 'to_date' is not defined

Tags: python, postgresql, date, psycopg2

I am writing a python script to insert values in a PostgreSQL 11.0 table. The column has a date information in format MonthYear (eg. May2016).

I am using following line in my code to insert the value.

```
q2 = """insert into %s.test_trial2enrollment_1 (trial_id, enrollment, enrollment_type, primary_completion_date, primary_completion_type, study_completion_date, study_completion_type, study_start, last_version_checked)
        values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');""" % (staging_schema, id_ ,enr_val, enr_type, to_date(prm_val, 'MonYYYY'), prm_type, to_date(end_val, 'MonYYYY'), end_type, sta, str(clinical_trial_version - 1))
        cur.execute(q2)
```

I am getting following error

```
NameError: name 'to_date' is not defined
```

How can I insert the date values with following format.

```
May2016
Nov2018
Mar2020
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: I really suggest You use `f strings` they will make the strings a lot more readable than formatting like this (python 3.6 and higher)

Comment: Please post an MCVE. What type of object are `prm_val` and `end_val`? What have you done to implement the function you need? Right now you have a vague set of potential requirements and no real question.

Comment: prm_val  and end_val are 'str' objects

Comment: @Matiiss, the string usage is correct for `psycopg2` to do the correct escaping. `f strings` are not the things to use in this case. The issue is that `to_date` is a Postgres function not a Python one.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver first of it was a suggestion and second, if psycopg2 doesn't throw an error at `f strings` they can be ceratainly used

Comment: They can be but they are dangerous and should not be used or encouraged: [String parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) "
Warning

Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. "

Answer (score 2):

To do this:

```
q2 = """insert into %s.test_trial2enrollment_1 (trial_id, enrollment, enrollment_type, primary_completion_date, primary_completion_type, study_completion_date, study_completion_type, study_start, last_version_checked)
        values (%s, %s, %s, %s, to_date(%s, 'MonYYYY'), %s, to_date(%s, 'MonYYYY'), %s, %s)"""
        cur.execute(q2, [staging_schema, id_ ,enr_val, enr_type, prm_val, prm_type, end_val, end_type, sta, str(clinical_trial_version - 1)])
```

Per docs here:

Passing parameters to SQL queries
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries